# Text not getting inserted into table, but only auto incrementing other column

Tags: asp.net

I have multiple `textboxes` that goes into a table called `dbo.skills`

```
dbo.Skills SkillID (PK- AutoIncrement) | SkillName
```

So when I used this method, the name is not getting stored but only SkillID is getting auto-incremented.  **Here is my .cs code**

```
 public void InsertSkillInfo()
    {


        String KKStech = @"Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=KKSTech;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(KKStech);

        try
        {

            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                conn.Open();

                //string skill = (TextBox)((Page.FindControl("TextBox" + i.ToString()))).Text;

                var skill = "";
                var control = Page.FindControl("TextBox" + i.ToString()) as TextBox;
                if (control != null)
                {
                    skill = control.Text;
                }
                const string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Skills (SkillName) VALUES (@SkillName)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SkillName", skill);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
```

After entering values in textboxes, table looks like this-

```
Dbo.Skills
SkillID | SkillName
1       | 
2       | 
3       | 
4       |
```

ASPX code:

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" class="caption" runat="server" Text="Skill Name"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" class="box" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br /> <br />

    <asp:Label ID="Label2" class="caption" runat="server" Text="Skill Name"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" class="box" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br /> <br />

    <asp:Label ID="Label3" class="caption" runat="server" Text="Skill Name"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" class="box" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br /> <br />

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="box" runat="server" Text="Insert" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" /> <br /><br /><br />
```

Comment: have you checked whether `skill` variable contain any value or not..

Comment: Yes I have- if (control != null).. Then I assigned skill = control.Text;

Comment: Are you sure the control is not null? (i.e debugged and tested it enters the if and value is set). Try hardcoding the skill value - if that works then the problem is with the way you try to get the value from the Textbox.

Comment: The control is actually set to NULL.. What problems am I facing here?

Comment: Can you show your mark-up as well? It is looking for controls with the IDs TextBox1, TextBox2,TextBox3 and TextBox4 - do these exist?

Comment: It does exists.. Please find my edit.

Comment: Are they nested inside something else like a panel? Page.FindControl() is *not* recursive - if controls are nested it won't find them.

Comment: I have copied the codes and pasted as is.. This is how it is used. Yes, the controls are found under for loop because there are multiple boxes that needs to be stored inside the table.